# Hibernate "ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP" column

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

In MySQL it is possible to make a TIMESTAMP row being updated on every update operation. Is there a way to realize this for a column with Hibernate and map it to a POJO property?

So that I have something like this:

```
@Column
private Date updated;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have this to accomplish this thing

```
@PreUpdate
protected void onUpdate() {
   updated = new Date();
}
```

Comment: and yes if you want to do it by DB side see axtavt's answer

Comment: I followed your approach,In my case its not working, values are going null. I am using Hibernate. Can you help. Below Answer works fine

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do it at the database side, you can specify a custom column definition (if schema is generated by Hibernate, otherwise you need to declare it in your schema as desired), and instruct Hibernate that this property is generated at the database side:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP")
@Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
private Date updated;
```

Alternatively, you can do it at the application side, as suggested by Jigar Joshi.

Comment: Will hibernate be able to make the mapping between java.lang.Date and TIMESTAMP? In my database Date always masp to DateTime.